# How are vanity addresses generated?

Tags: vanity-address

The gambling site [satoshi bones](http://bitzillions.com/satoshibones) uses addresses that start with `1bones`, such as

```
1bonesEeTcABPjLzAb1VkFgySY6Zqu3sX
```

How did they generate such a vanity address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are applications, which take the starting text and generates milions of new addresses until the generated address starts with the selected text. It's pretty fast for short strings (3 characters). you'll wait about few minutes for 5 characters (case insensitive).

one such application is [vanitygen](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen).

Comment: Are there problems importing the private key? Can these be imported into online services like Coinbase?

Comment: I use vanity adresses in bitcoind and blockchain.info (see this [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys)) but I don't think, it is not possible to import your own addresses into Coinbase.

Comment: There used to be an address generator with prefix selection in inputs.io... Coinbase is similar type of service. You don't have any own addresses. You just have your account and they give you some their addresses bound to your account. Is that correct?

Comment: @V-X Yes, that's one reason why Coinbase.com isn't that secure.